# How to draw RelativeLayout to canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, android-relativelayout

I want to draw a `RelativeLayout` with all it's children to `Canvas`.

This is what I been trying to do:

```
    // from View constructor
    container = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.containerLayout, null);

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        container.layout(0,0, w, h);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);
        container.draw(canvas);
    }
```

I debug and saw that `onSizeChanged` is called with good values. Also this code works for `ImageView`, so how is `RelativeLayout` different?

My problem is that it doesn't draw on screen, I don't seen any of its children. How to solve this?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I added clarification for the question. My problem is that it's now showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding RelativeLAyout.mesure() solves the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    container.measure(w, h);
    container.layout(0,0, w, h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below example.
It is working fine at my end

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView.setText("This is example");
layout.addView(textView);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);

layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
layout.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: wrap the textview with a relative layout and tell me if it works, this is exactly the difference in my example

Comment: it just an example, give more description about you problem or source code